# @Produces @Named gives a WELD-001408

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I'm trying to get my head around CDI and in this case the annotations `@Produces` and `@Named`

I have the following code

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class cdiTest {

@Inject
protected CDIModel em;

@Test
public void injectionTest(){
    Assert.assertEquals("this", em.getMyString());
}

}

public class CDIModel {

String myString;

public CDIModel(String myString) {
    this.myString = myString;
}

public String getMyString() {
    return myString;
}
}

public class EntityProducer {

@Produces
@Named("this")
@Singleton
public CDIModel doThis() {
    return new CDIModel("this");
}

@Produces
@Named("that")
@Singleton
public CDIModel doThat() {
    return new CDIModel("that");
}

}
```

Why do i get

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied 
dependencies for type CDIModel with qualifiers @Named
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Named protected 
persistence.dao.cdiTest.em
  at persistence.dao.cdiTest.em(cdiTest.java:0)
```

After adding @AdditionalClasses(EntityProducer.class) I get

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous 
dependencies for type CDIModel with qualifiers @Default
at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected 
dk.nykredit.lanc.persistence.dao.cdiTest.em
at dk.nykredit.lanc.persistence.dao.cdiTest.em(cdiTest.java:0)
Possible dependencies: 
- Producer Method [CDIModel] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] declared 
as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Named @Singleton public 
persistence.dao.EntityProducer.doThat()],
- Producer Method [CDIModel] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] declared 
as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Named @Singleton public 
persistence.dao.EntityProducer.doThis()]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDI-Unit does not scan all classes so it does not knwo about `EntityProducer` class. So you must manually add classes/packages that you want to be scanned by CDI.

You can use the `@AdditionalClasses` annotation :

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@AdditionalClasses(EntityProducer.class)
public class cdiTest {
    ....
    ....

}
```

**EDIT**

Then you got an ambigous dependency because you did not properly qualified your injection. You should use `@Named("this")` or `@Named("that")` in the test class :

```
@Inject
@Named("this") // or @Named("that")
protected CDIModel em;
```

*Note also that in CDI we usually use `@Qualifier` instead of `@Named`*

Comment: That did something, but now I receive a WELD-001409 on the 2 produces methods. I have edited the initial text to show the error